# Remove nodes from a Binary Search Tree in C

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I want to remove nodes from a binary search tree. In this function there are 3 parameters. One of them tree, the others are start node and end node. I want to remove nodes between start node and end node. 
P.S : The user write start node and end node and we use them as parameters.

The code which I write :

```
node * removeReviewsBetween(node * tree,double start,double end){
    node * newNode;
    if(tree==NULL){
        return NULL;
    }


    if(start< tree->scoreNumber){
        tree->left=removeReviewsBetween(tree->left,start,end);
    }

    else if(start > tree->scoreNumber){
        tree->right=removeReviewsBetween(tree->right,start,end);
    }

    else{
        if(tree->right && tree->left){
            newNode=findMin(tree->right);
            tree->scoreNumber=newNode->scoreNumber;
            tree->right=removeReviewsBetween(tree->left,tree->scoreNumber,end);
        }

        else{
            newNode=tree;
            if(tree->left==NULL){
                tree=tree->right;
            }
            else if(tree->right==NULL){
                tree=tree->left;
            }
            free(newNode);
        }

        return tree;
    }
}
```

I write someting but it doens't work correctly. Please give me some advice

Comment: please tell us what exactly isn't working. also show us your node struct

Comment: @PhilippMurry  it doesn't check to tree has start and end  nodes .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do it - your code slightly modified:

```
node *removeReviewsBetween(node *tree, double start, double end){
    node *newNode;
    double score;

    if(tree==NULL){
        return NULL;
    }

    while (tree->scoreNumber >= start && tree->scoreNumber =< end){  // if head is in the range to  delete
        if(tree->right){
            newNode = findMin(tree->right);
            score = newNode->scoreNumber;
            removeReviewsBetween(tree, score, score);
            tree->scoreNumber = score;
            continue;
        }

        if(tree->left){
            newNode = findMax(tree->left);
            score = newNode->scoreNumber;
            removeReviewsBetween(tree, score, score);
            tree->scoreNumber = score;
            continue;
        }

        return NULL;  // if the only node left is the head and it's still in the range to delete
    }

    if(end < tree->scoreNumber){  // if all nodes to delete are in the left subtree
        tree->left = removeReviewsBetween(tree->left, start, end);
        return tree;
    }

    else if(start > tree->scoreNumber){  // if all nodes to delete are in the right subtree
        tree->right = removeReviewsBetween(tree->right, start, end);
        return tree;
    }           
}
```

Comment: thank you it works correctly but there is some problems and I don't fix it. For example my scoreNumbers are between 1 and 10 and when user write start=0 and end=11 it deletes all tree but this numbers aren't in the range. @striving_coder

Comment: @user3142663: What do you mean they are not in the range? May be we're talking past each other, but to me when user submits command with range parameters `start = 0` and `end = 11` it means "delete all nodes with values between 0 and 11 inclusively" and if the values of all nodes in your tree are between 1 and 10, all of the nodes of the tree fall within the specified range, so the whole tree is to be deleted. If that's not the way you want it, you need to re-specify your objective.